GetToken BadRequest
I keep getting BadRequest but I want to receive invalid_scope error message in the exception.
         try
            {
                auto credentials = this->GetCredentials();
                auto token = credentials->GetToken(m_token_request_context, m_context);    
                return token;
            }
            catch(Azure::Core::Credentials::AuthenticationException& e)
            {
                std::string error_message = std::string("Failed to GetToken. Error: ") + e.what();
                throw std::runtime_error(error_message);   
            }    

For the credentials I am using ClientSecretCredential.
In the m_token_request_context I am setting tenantId and scope (if empty set to default)
For m_context I am not setting anything, do I need to add something there?
I tried to catch different exceptions, to pass different arguments.
I expected to receive invalid_scope as I message in the exception when I pass invalid scope to the m_token_request_context

Are you trying to generate access token for Microsoft Graph API?

No, I am using it for Azure Blob Storage

Then you need to pass scope as https://storage.azure.com/.default

I know that, but I want to detect if someone set invalid scope and report that problem.
